# webView.canGoBack() not working when using loadDataWithBaseURL()

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have a `WebView` in my application that displays HTML data downloaded from a webpage. Why do I load the HTML rather than the URL alone? Well, in order for me to allow offline search, I download the HTML data and store it on an SQL database.

Everything works well, and subsequent calls to `loadDataWithBaseUrl()` work well, and keep on loading correctly on my `WebView`, but whenever the user presses the back key, the user is just taken back to the last activity on the stack, rather than going back.

I tried using the following code:

```
// Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
    myWebView.goBack();
    return true;
}
```

But then I tried forcing the `WebView` to go back, without checking if it could or not, via:

```
// Check if the key event was the Back button and if there's history
if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
    myWebView.goBack();
    return true;
}
```

but nothing happens, it just stays on the same place.

As an FYI, I've tried passing `null` and an actual URL when calling `loadData()`, here's how I have it set right now:

```
view.loadDataWithBaseURL(mUrl, mHtmlData, SearchUtils.MIME_TYPE, SearchUtils.CHARSET, "");
```

I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686933/android-webview-can-render-html-going-forward-but-not-backward) but I am hoping for better luck.

Comment: Could you try using the step method in place of goBack and pass is a param of (-1) each time ?

Comment: Try this Create own canGoBack by like this.... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48318991/7181583

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I actually decided to implement my own "back" functionality, not sure if this will work for everybody´s intentions, but it worked for me.

First,

Create an `ArrayList` that will store the urls you visit in chronological order.

```
private ArrayList<String> searchHistory;
```

from `onCreate()` initialize it:

```
searchHistory = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now, each time you load a url, simply add the url string to the history:

```
String mUrl = "www.example.com";
searchHistory.add(mUrl);
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mUrl,...);
```

And, when user presses back, handle that by removing the eldest entry of the array, and then loading the last one remaining after deletion:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {     
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && searchHistoryPos > 0) {
        Constants.LogMessage("Handling back keyevent");
        //remove eldest entry
        searchHistory.remove(mUrl);
        //make the url-to-load be the latest entry after deletion
        mUrl = searchHistory.get(searchHistory.size);
        //load the new url
        mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(mUrl...);
        }
    }
```

Of course, when calling loadDataWithBaseUrl, I am also passing the pre-loaded HTML data.

Hope that helps!

Comment: did you also save html data with urls?

Answer (score 1):

another simple solution is to save the first url and than check if is equal to the current url

field :

```
String mFirstUrlLoaded = "";
```

than  :

```
mFirstUrlLoaded = "your first url.....";
```

than :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!mFirstUrlLoaded.equals(mWebView.getUrl())) { 
        mWebView.goBack();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

put first link on history field

```
view.loadDataWithBaseURL(mUrl, mHtmlData, SearchUtils.MIME_TYPE, SearchUtils.CHARSET, mUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String mFirstUrlLoaded = "";



mFirstUrlLoaded = "your first url.....";



@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!mFirstUrlLoaded.equals(mWebView.getUrl())) { 
        mWebView.goBack();
}
```

This works for me..